# Creating multiple interfaces on OpenStack Instances

Tags: kvm-virtualization, openstack

I'm able to have OpenStack up and running with no issues and I'm loving it, however, I'm trying to create extra interfaces on one of my instances and I read under openstack documentation that is possible.
[OpenStack-Using-Multi-Nics](http://docs.openstack.org/essex/openstack-compute/admin/content/using-multi-nics.html)

Has anyone been able to follow this article and successfully create multiple interfaces on instances?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I am little late on this. Anyways, I just successfully configured multi interface with ice house and ubuntu 14.04. I am using flatdhcp nova network configuration. Following are the steps.

1. Create 2 n/w using nova network-create command, each with 2 different bridges (say br100 and br101)
2. Then launch an instance attaching these 2 n/w.
3. By default using ubuntu 14.04 cloud image, only eth0 is configured. So image comes up with eth0 having ip address allocated. We see from openstack dashboard that instance has been assigned 2 IPs (one from each n/w) but that is from openstack viewpoint.
4. You can login to this new instance using eth0 ip and key pair. Once you are in, change `/etc/network/interfaces` to have `auto eth1 and iface eth1 inet dhcp`. Once you add these 2 lines execute `sudo ifdown eth1 && sudo ifup eth1` (note that normal networking restart commands are not functional in 14.04 )
   and then you have it :)

Answer (score -1):

I also follow this link to configure. It is possible to use two NICs on instance.

But when the instance startup, the IPs failed to bind to the NIC. Then I have to login with VNC and bind the IP with each network interface.

Comment: Euler, I had the same issue as well, but how do I bind the IPs to each instance NICs to get it up and running? I don't want to re-install OpenStack again from scratch. Thanks in advance.